# Nested for loop, run series 10000 times

Tags: c, for-loop, nested

Could I ask for input on what I might be **doing wrong**, please.
I am trying to run my *inner* `for` loop `10000` times, but after the first *print out*, I am getting **infinity** as the printed value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i, f = 1;
float calculation = 0;

int main()
{
    for(int j=0; j<=10000; j++)
    {
        for(i=1; i<=19; i++)
        {
            f = f * i;
            calculation += 1.00 / f;
        }

        printf("Factorial calculation is 1/ %d!=%f\n", i, calculation);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What result did you expect?

Comment: Your `int` variable `f` is unlikely to be able to contain 19! = 121645100408832000, a 57-bit number.

Comment: No I'm sorry maybe I should explain further. So my inner loop calculates 1.00/factorial, up to 20!. I can execute this fine and have the print statement print out the sum of this = 1.718282. But when I try to place this 'for' loop nested in another 'for' loop, with the hope to execute this 10,000 times, i.e I would like to see "Factorial calculation is 20! = 1.718282" 10,000, I end up getting the first print out of "Factorial calculation is 20! = 1.718282", but then the following values read ""Factorial calculation is 20! = inf". Thank you for replying.

Comment: Note that your print statement is incorrect in any case.  Even if all the types involved had arbitrary precision, the final value of `calculation` would *not* be 19!, not even on the first iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: If you want to perform the same computation over 10000 times, then you need to reset `f` to the same initial value each time.  The code presented fails to do that.

Comment: You can't hold 20! in a 32-bit `int` only up to 12! You'll find that `f` overflows and becomes `0`, hence the infinity from dividing by `0`.

Comment: Apologies, the calculation calculates and stores 1/20! not 20!. The printf statement has been amended in the original post.

Comment: May I humbly suggest that you are *not* actually calculating 1.00/factorial, up to 20!. I suspect you're correctly computing it up to the 1/12! term, and then adding in random garbage after `f` overflows.  But if the random garbage in `f` is always big, `1/f` will be small, and won't perturb the sum too much.

Comment: Maybe, but it's still wrong. The factorial is computed as `109641728` but it has overflowed. That is less than 12! which is `479001600`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the replies, I appreciate it! I will go and research how to solve integer overflow, thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Apologies I am very new to coding, only 3 weeks experience.

Comment: `for(int j=0; j<=10000; j++)` is actually 10001 iterations. You want `<`, not `<=`.

Comment: Thank you Ninja, I appreciate that, I'll adjust in my own code.

Answer (score 2):

You have an *integer overflow*. Look, you define `f` as `int`

```
 int i, f = 1;
```

and `f` grows fast and becomes **huge**, at the end it must have been `(19!)^10000` (quite a big `19!` raised into `10000` power); however, `int` value *can not* be greater than `2^31 - 1`, and so the integer overflow comes (you can get *negative values*, then *positive one*, *zero*).

When `i == 18`, `j == 1` it appears, that `f == 0` and from now you have

```
 // when i == 18, j = 1 we have f == 0 due to integer overflow
 calculation += 1.00 / f;
```

equals to **infinity**.

Quick amendment is to declare `f` as `float`:

```
 int i; 
 float f = 1.0;
```

The computation is still ineffcient, but the `calculation` is now valid.

```
calculation == 1.7182816
```

**Edit:** note, that `f` *grows fast*, at `j = 2`, `i = 8` we have `f == infinity`. From now on we *start doing nothing*:

```
1.00 / infinity == 0
```

and that's why

```
calculation += 1.00 / f;
```

equals to

```
calculation += 0;
```

We can well rewrite

```
// we don't want add 0 9997 times
for(int j=0; j<=10000; j++) ...
```

into (all we want is at most `4` outer loops instead of `10000`)

```
for(int j=0; j<=3; j++) ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Could I ask would a recursion make it more efficient or is that irrelevant to this?

Comment: @Steph Nolan: inefficiency is in the outer loop: you operate with *huge* numbers, that's why from `i == 8`, `j == 2` you have `f == infinity`, `1.00 / f == 0` and that's why you have `10000 -3` times you do nothing: `calculation += 0`. You can well change outer loop into `for(int j=0; j<=3; j++)`

Comment: @StephNolan Yes, recursion is irrelevant to the more serious problems.

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko Thank you for taking the time to explain it to me!

Comment: @Steph Nolan: it was quite intersting to catch the felon in disguise: *integer overflow*